# Node-gallery standalone example, //error event, ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, image-gallery

I have problem with node-gallery npm module. Inside /example dir, after dependency instalation, I'v try to run an app. I had result on localhost:3000/gallery, but when page loading is done, I have this error on console:

```
node-gallery listening on localhost:3000
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn convert ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:383:13)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:407:11)
```

Also, on page, one of images is not loaded. On inspect view I'v seen that visible image has no extension:

```
/gallery/Ireland?tn=1
```

Broken image link have:

```
/gallery/dolough.jpg?tn=1
```

I try to run only standalone example, I have no any extra cone, nothing more than github res.

Please for hints. 
Regards

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/cianclarke/node-gallery)

Comment: Did you install [ImageMagick](https://github.com/cianclarke/node-gallery#imagemagick) as well?

Comment: Of course, like in package.json: 
"imagemagick-stream": "^1.1.0".

Comment: That doesn't seem to actually install ImageMagick (which is a suite of programs independent of Node). You should follow the instructions that I linked to, the error you're getting is thrown because the `convert` executable, which is part of ImageMagick, can't be found.

Comment: Now I see, I haven't seen that... Thanks for a solution! Natural mistake...xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line suggests that ImageMagick isn't installed:

```
Error: spawn convert ENOENT
```

(`convert` is part of the ImageMagick suite, `ENOENT` means that Node wasn't able to find that file/executable)

The solution would be to properly install ImageMagick. Installation instructions can be found [in the `node-gallery` README](https://github.com/cianclarke/node-gallery#imagemagick).

Comment: In fact, console said about convert error. Thanks a lot, that's how I thought after first hint, I see this is convert tool, and also I have problem only with static photos with extensions. Should I install it from homebrew linux port, or sudo apt-get?

Comment: Probably `apt-get`, but it depends on how up-to-date your Linux distro is.